# Cuda create texture object from black/white image

Tags: c++, cuda, textures, cuda-arrays

I'm trying to process a video, frame by frame. To do this I want to create a texture containing the current frame and pass it to the kernel. The frames are 1440*1080 pixel with each pixel being represented by an unsigned char, e.g. 8 bit.

I followed the instructions, however my program always fails at the point where the texture is created. Error-Code 0x11: "invalid arguments".

Here is my code:

```
// allocate cuda array in device memory
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = 
   cudaCreateChannelDesc(8, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindUnsigned);
cudaArray* cuArray;
cudaMallocArray(&cuArray, &channelDesc, width, height);

// copy frame_in to device memory
int size = width * height * sizeof(char);
cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray, 0, 0, frame_in.data, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// specify texture
cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
resDesc.res.array.array = cuArray;

// specify texture object parameters
cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
texDesc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
texDesc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
texDesc.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
texDesc.normalizedCoords = 1;

// !FAILS! create texture object
cudaTextureObject_t texObj = NULL;
cudaCreateTextureObject(&texObj, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, I forgot the memset() for the cudaTextureDesc. Should read:

```
// specify texture object parameters
cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
texDesc.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
texDesc.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
texDesc.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
texDesc.readMode = cudaReadModeElementType;
texDesc.normalizedCoords = 1;
```